# Should I put all data in one table for Implementing Filtration or use junction table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design, filtering

I thought about using a junction table to avoid repeating the data in my database.

So I have the following schema

Apartments:

```html
+----+-------+----------+------------------+        
| ID | Price |  CityID  |  ContractTypeID  |       
+----+-------+----------+------------------+        
|  1 |  200  |    1     |         1        |    
|  2 |  150  |    1     |         2        |
|  3 |  400  |    1     |         2        |  
+----+-------+----------+------------------+
```

AmenityTypes:

```html
+----+-------------+        
| ID |     Name    |      
+----+-------------+        
|  1 |  Building   |   
|  2 |  Kitchen    |
|  3 |  Furniture  |  
+----+-------+-----+
```

Amenities:

```html
+----+----------+--------------+    
| ID |  TypeID  |     Name     | 
+----+----------+--------------+
|  1 |     1    |   Security   |
|  2 |     1    |   Parking    |
|  3 |     2    |   Fridge     |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

ApartmentAmenities:

```html
+-------------+-----------+    
| ApartmentID | AmenityID |     
+-------------+-----------+
|      1      |     1     |
|      1      |     2     |
|      2      |     1     |
|      2      |     2     |
|      2      |     3     |
+-------------+-----------+
```

My question now, how to apply some filters for example I need all the apartments in CityID 1, Price < 400, Has a Fridge and Security.

Also is this is the best approach db-design wise to achieve what I want to do.

**Expected Result:**

> AppartmentID: 2, Building Features: Security, Kitchen Features: Fridge

**Update: My current working approach**

```
SELECT Price, ID, Amenities.Name as 'Amenity' FROM Apartments
INNER JOIN ApartmentAmenities ON ApartmentAmenities.ApartmentID = Apartments.ID
INNER JOIN Amenities ON ApartmentAmenities.AmenityID = Amenities.ID

WHERE PropertyAmenities.AmenityID IN (1,2) AND Apartments.Price < 300 AND CityID=1
```

*Note: I'm using a different data in my DB that posted here but my focus is about the approach*

Comment: What's connecting apartments to cities? Read about the different [join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) types.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't include the whole schema but I wanted to focus on the complicated part for me. Cities is in a separate table maintaining a normal 1:M relation with Apartments. I appreciate your help but I have some knowledge about this not my first time, but I've been rusty for a long time and I need help to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use do a filter on your amenities and then do a group per apartment and check if all the filters are satisfied. then join back to your apartment for additional filters. Something like this. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c7f9/1)

```
SELECT AP.ID
FROM Apartments AP
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT AA.ApartmentID
    FROM ApartmentAmenities AA
    INNER JOIN Amenities A ON A.ID = AA.AmenityID
    INNER JOIN AmenityTypes AT ON AT.ID = A.TypeID
    WHERE (AT.Name = 'Kitchen' AND A.Name = 'Fridge') OR (AT.Name = 'Building' AND A.Name = 'Security')
    GROUP BY AA.ApartmentID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT A.Name) = 2
)AA 
ON AP.ID = AA.ApartmentID
WHERE CityID = 1 AND  Price < 400
```

You can refer these links for more info.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: Ok I tried to apply your code but I got errors: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "AA.AmenityID" could not be bound.

I tried a couple things and one of them worked for me, I updated my question and it would be helpful to advise if my approach is good

Comment: In your example `ApartmentAmenities` table has  `AmenityID` column. is the column with the same name in your database as well?

Comment: @e7naonline - Added a sql fiddle. you can use the above logic and modify it appropriately if your schema or naming convention is different.

Comment: I wanted to simplify my question so I used different names, my bad. I fixed my typos everything is almost good. 1- The first WHERE clause generates the error "The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator." so I replaced it with LIKE Operator. 2- HAVING condition results in "Operand data type text is invalid for count operator."

Comment: why are your `Name` columns of `text` datatype? text columns are Large Object  types which are used to store textual data upto a length of 2,147,483,647 characters. based on your question, your Name columns should be `VARCHAR / NVARCHAR`. Refer this for datatypes in sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187752.aspx

Comment: Noted about the TEXT data type. it seems to be okay however the logic hear depends on counting the feature name twice to qualify instead of using AND operator in the first WHERE clause which will not work when I input the rest of the data. So I was wondering what do you think of my approach in my Update

Comment: `PropertyAmenities.AmenityID IN (1,2)` does not guarantee that the related Apartment will have both AmenityID 1,2. Even if an apartment has amenity = 1, it will still show up in your results. your question is an example of Relational Division with Remainder. Check this post https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/